# gcc/ld: what is to -Wl,-rpath in dynamic linking what -l is to -L in static linking?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, gcc, ld

**With /my/dir/path/foo.a and /my/dir/path/bar.a:**

To statically link using gcc/g++, one uses `-L` to specify the directory containing the static libraries and `-l` to specify the name of the library. In this case one would write `gcc -L/my/dir/path -lfoo -lbar ...`.

**With /my/dir/path/foo.so and /my/dir/path/bar.so:**

To dynamically link using gcc/g++, one uses `-Wl,-rpath,/my/dir/path`. How are the names of the libraries specified? Is the command `gcc -L/my/dir/path -Wl,-rpath,/my/dir/path -lfoo -lbar ...` correct? Or should it be `gcc -L/my/dir/path -Wl,-rpath,/my/dir/path -Wl,-lfoo -Wl,-lbar ...`? In other words, do the library names need to be passed on to the linker through `-Wl,-l`?

Answer (score 14):

The `-l` argument works well for both static and shared libraries but expects the filename of specified library to be in a specific format. Namely, `-lfoo` tells the linker to look for a file named `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so`. If you want to links against a library whose filename don't have this 'lib' prefix (i. e. `foo.so`), you can use a semicolon and specify a filename: `-l:foo.so`.

So, to dynamically link against `/my/dir/path/foo.so` and `/my/dir/path/bar.so` you need to issue the following command:

```
g++ -L/my/dir/path/ -l:foo.so -l:bar.so
```

As for `-rpath`, it has the `-rpath=<path>` format, so in order to pass it to the linked you need the issue the following:

```
g++ -L/my/dir/path/ -Wl,-rpath=/my/dir/path/ -l:foo.so -l:bar.so
```