# Dynamic library can't find Object files causing failures

Tags: c++, jar, g++, java-native-interface

I have a jar file. It has some JNI code that is using some C/C++ code I have. I tried to generate a Library to make it easier to package together and deploy.

However when I try to run the code the library complains it can't find the .o files that it was built from. If I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after copying the Object files it will all work. This seems to be a bad practice.

The g++ command I am using to generate the library is: `g++ -shared -fPIC -o libfoobar.so foo.o foo_bar.o bar_foo.o foo_api.o -lc -ludev`

Can I have g++ automatically package it together so I don't need to manually copy it?

Comment: Specify the rpath,see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378137/2991525 ;Note:Imho it's much simpler to make use of CMake to do something like this:It doesn't restrict you to a specific compiler & also reduces/eliminates the need of juggling with compiler options. It would simply be a `project(FooBar) add_library(foobar SHARED foo.c foo_bar.c bar_foo.c foo_api.c) target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE c udev) set_target_properties(foobar PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN")` (assuming everything ends up in the same dir). Furthermore there's this https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJNI.html

Comment: @fabian I have seen the rpath, but it looks like it makes me still specify the directory which would require the file to be manually copied to the production instance? Is it not possible to just copy the .so file over with nothing else and not need to specify anything else?

Comment: Rpaths can be relative to the directory containing the so file (if it includes `$ORIGIN`) or absolute. You can even specify multiple alternatives providing fallbacks...